# Prolog conditional statements

Tags: prolog

Suppose we are given certain facts and we were supposed to write a certain rule that explores a given condition in those facts, for example, if we are given certain climates and their characteristics:

```
climate(jun, 20, snow, wind, cold).
climate(jul, 20, hot, dry, calm).
climate(sep, 15, calm, dry, cool).
climate(sep, 16, rain, hot, calm).
climate(sep, 18, warm, rain, calm).
climate(oct, 29, cool, dry, calm).
climate(nov, 1, cold, snow, wind).
climate(nov, 5, hot, snow, wind).
climate(dec, 15, warm, rain, wind).
climate(dec, 21, wind, cold, dry).
```

If we wanted to find out which climates were hot and dry, would we do something like this:

```
climatecheck(Month) :-
   climate(Month, _, hot, _, _);
   climate(Month, _, _, hot, _);
   climate(Month, _, _, _, hot),
   climate(Month, _, dry, _, _);
   climate(Month, _, _, dry, _);
   climate(Month, _, _, _, dry).
```

I tried the method above but it doesnt seem to work.

Instead of giving me:

```
Month = jul.
```

It gives me all the months which have EITHER hot or dry climates.

What could I be doing wrong, despite outlining specific positions of each characteristic with "and" and "or" conditionals? Thank you.

Comment: Which version of prolog are you using? I just tried your code and I'm receiving the correct answer... different compilers may handle operators precedence in a different order, use parenthesis to enforce it.

Comment: The facts don't appear to be very logically organized. I would think you might have a variable collection of climate conditions, in which case you'd have a small list, like `climate(jun, 20, [hot, dry, breezy])`. If there are always exactly 3 conditions (as you show) but each in a specific category, they should be assignable to a fixed variable position: `climate(Month, Day, Wind, Temperature, Precipitation)`. Then your predicate becomes `climatecheck(Month) :- climate(Month, _, _, hot, dry).`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use parentheses to force the precedence in evaluating your predicate:

```
climatecheck(Month) :-
   (  climate(Month, _, hot, _, _)
   ;  climate(Month, _, _, hot, _)
   ;  climate(Month, _, _, _, hot)
   ),
   (  climate(Month, _, dry, _, _)
   ;  climate(Month, _, _, dry, _)
   ;  climate(Month, _, _, _, dry)
   ).
```

Comment: in a sense, this could not be what OP called for - it requires `Month` to be a `primary key` of climate/5

Answer (score 2):

```
climatecheck(Month) :-
   climate(Month, _, X, Y, Z),
   % overkill generalization ahead :)
   maplist([P]>>memberchk(P, [X,Y,Z]), [hot, dry]).

?- climatecheck(Month).
Month = jul ;
false.
```

Comment: Oh my... Thanks for the master class :-)